# How to force a "Buy-Signal" to reactivate ASAP after a Trailing Stop-Loss closes in profit, if conditions for initial Entry are still being met?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I'm building a second-based strategy (currently on 5sec candles to limit the amount of alerts), it's working great in backtesting, but I think it can be optimized even further.

Let's say I work with an indicator which triggers a simple `buySignal` and `sellSignal` (one must follow the other without repetition), I've set my `strategy.entry/close` based on those signals (duh.) and added a Trailing Stop-Loss `useTrailStop` so tight that it often Exits (in profit 80% of the time) one, two, maybe max three candles after Entry (1sec or 5 sec).

Ok, cool, I'm making good profit and it's a steady growth over time, but then I'm missing-out on every big price swings because the profit-taking happened way too soon, and the next `buySignal` can only happen AFTER the following `sellSignal`. So...

Is there any way to reactivate my buySignal to trigger as-soon-as-possible after Exit if the conditions for my initial Long Entry are still being met ?

Here comes the code, stripped down to the basics.

```
// Risk management inputs (settings) :
//If one of you knows how to translate this part in percentages, something about input.float I think, I'd love to know.

inpTrailStop    = input(defval = 200, title = "Trailing Stop Loss", minval = 0)
inpTrailOffset  = input(defval = 0, title = "Trailing Stop Loss Offset", minval = 0)

// === RISK MANAGEMENT Back-end ===
// if an input is less than 1, assuming not wanted so we assign 'na' value to disable it.

useTrailStop    = inpTrailStop   >= 1 ? inpTrailStop   : na
useTrailOffset  = inpTrailOffset >= 1 ? inpTrailOffset : na

// Strategy backtesting signals Buy / Close :

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, 1, when=buySignal)
strategy.close("Long", when=sellSignal)

// === STRATEGY RISK MANAGEMENT EXECUTION ===

strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry = "Long", trail_points = useTrailStop, trail_offset = useTrailOffset )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to monitor for the last trade being closed with `strategy.exit`  (comment of the closed trade will be "Trail" in that case), and check if position has changed, and then enter Long.

```
// Strategy backtesting signals Buy / Close :


if (buySignal) or (ta.change(strategy.closedtrades) and strategy.closedtrades.exit_comment(strategy.closedtrades -1) == "Trail")
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, 1)

if sellSignal
    strategy.close("Long")

// === STRATEGY RISK MANAGEMENT EXECUTION ===

strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry = "Long", trail_points = useTrailStop, trail_offset = useTrailOffset, comment = "Trail")
```

Comment: but side note - the entry still will be at bar close / or next tick with calc_on_every_tick activated

Comment: My friend, I don't think you realise what you've just done for me.

Profit has been catapulted x10 with this simple tweak, and I was already on the bar-close calculation + magnifier to make sure there wasn't multiple signals on a singe candle. 

Leave me your contact, if there is any way I can give back to you once I manage to set this from virtual to online, I will.